# How to delay the next scroll event after the first one?

Tags: jquery, scroll, delay

I have this `jQuery` function which acts like an infinite scroll:

```
$('.box.scroll').bind('scroll', function () {
if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
    console.log(".scrollTop() = " + $(this).scrollTop() + " .innerHeight() = " + $(this).innerHeight() + " scrollHeight = " + $(this)[0].scrollHeight);
    console.log("ms: " + new Date().getMilliseconds());

    getData();
}
});
```

This is the result of what got printed to the `console.log()` function:

> ms: 458  ms: 505

The difference between the first and next scroll happen too fast, there is only 47 ms. Because of this I get weird results. I need at least 1 second delay.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you looked into setTimeout and setInterval javascript functions? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Comment: debounce event, see e.g: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Comment: That script works as smooth as whatever works that smooth! Doing an `AJAX` calls too and it describes that it is used for that as well. Great script, thank you very much! Can't accept unless you answer the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
var addScrollListener = (function(){
    var interval = 300,
        checkInterval = interval+75;
    var last = 0, timer = null, queue = false, el;
    function check(){ if(queue) main(false); }
    function main(addQueue){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        last = new Date().getTime();
        queue = false;
        if(addQueue) timer = setTimeout(check, checkInterval);
        el.onscrollhandler.call(el);
    }
    function handler() {
        el = this;
        if(new Date().getTime() > last+interval) main(true);
        else queue = true;
    }
    return function(el, f) {
        el.onscroll = handler;
        el.onscrollhandler = f;
    };
})();

addScrollListener(element, handler);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LJ8BB/)